# WSO2 EMM - WIFI operation not working

Tags: android, wso2, android-wifi, wso2-iot

I am testing device management operation, but wifi setting not working.
The difference between wifi set using emm and defualt is security type which is WPA PSK and EMM device management set it to WEP.
How can I modify the security type?

More info:

server : windows 7 (wso2 v : 1.1.0),client : galaxy note 10.1 (android), database : mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the security type in EMM. It currently supports only WEP.

Thanks